# Div that appears behind other. How to avoid that behaivor?

Tags: jquery, css

I'm using JQuery for this. The problem is that, when I drag an object from the side bar, the DIV that I'm dragging appears behind the main area, thus it looks really bad. I took a screenshot of the problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pckKo.png

The div I'm dragging has this CSS:

`.reporte_arrastrado{
    width: 150px;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: silver;
    background-image: url(chart.png);
    background-position: left center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding: 10px 0 10px 26px;
    position:relative;
}`

And, the one that represents the main area has this CSS:

`#tabs{
    position:relative;
}`

That's it... I've read some answers here, and people always suggest to set the position property to relative. But, it does not work for me.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to set the z-index of your draggable DIV.

ie:

```
#dragger {
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  width: ...

}
```

Comment: Thanks... I've been playing with the z-index as you suggest. The only way I was able to make the DIV appears in front of the container was by setting the container z-index to -99.

But, this brings another problem: the container has a group of gadgets that are draggable too. Once I set the z-index of the container to -99, I cannot drag its gadgets.

Any idea? I'll keep trying to fix it anyway. Thanks again for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Well... since I don't have too much time at all... I just change the z-index from JQuery dinamically. This is what I did:

```
$('#stuff').draggable({
    start: function(){
        $('#tabs').css('z-index', '-9999');
    },
    stop: function(){
        $('#tabs').css('z-index', '0');
    }
});
```

Thank you so much.